# How do I open another port in a docker nginx container (only in the container; so, NOT publishing which is the -p flag)?

Tags: docker, nginx

On my local laptop.

I'm learning about ports and Docker and am having problems using different ports in nginx. I would like to start an nginx container and specify a port, open the container shell, and test the web server with curl on the port I specified. In Docker, I've tried to use `--expose <different_port_here>` and also tried `-e NGINX_PORT=<different_port_here>` when creating the container but none of them worked. Only the default port 80 works.

Anybody know how I can open a different port within my container? I DON'T want to publish and forward the port outside the container.

## Attempt 1

The first thing I tried was to use `--expose <different_port_here>`

`docker run --name my-nginx-container-w-expose -d --expose 100 nginx:stable-perl`

When I do `docker ps` it shows port 100/tcp and 80/tcp so I thought that port 100 would also be open now.

Then I go into the shell and try curl with the following commands

`docker exec -it my-nginx-container-w-expose /bin/bash`

`curl http://localhost:<different_port_here>`

Return the following below:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 100: Connection refused

## Attempt 2

The 2nd thing I tried was to use `-e NGINX_PORT=<different_port_here>`

`docker run --name my-nginx-container-w-env-variable -d nginx:stable-perl`

When I do `docker ps` it does NOT shows port 100/tcp but shows 80/tcp.

Then I go into the shell and try curl with the following commands

`docker exec -it my-nginx-container-w-env-variable /bin/bash`

`curl http://localhost:<different_port_here>`

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 100: Connection refused

## The only port I can use is 80

The only port which curl works with when in the container is 80.

`curl http://localhost:80`

Return

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does Nginx listen on ports that you're trying to connect (e.g with `curl`)?  Check it with the following command `netstat -tlpn` inside a container.  At first, you have to define a `server` in the Nginx configurations with your preferred port  (as defined the default one for the `80` port)

Comment: I wasn't able to install `netstat` in the container so I'm not sure. All I know is that using `curl https://localhost:80` works but not any other port I tried to open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nginx configuration tells nginx which ports to listen on. If you have a file called nginx.conf like this

```
server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
                index index.html;
                root /usr/share/nginx/site1;
                try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
        }
}

server {
        listen 100;
        location / {
                index index.html;
                root /usr/share/nginx/site2;
                try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
        }
}
```

nginx will listen on port 80 and port 100 and serve different content on the two ports.

If you then make a Dockerfile like this

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/site1 && \
    mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/site2 && \
    echo Site1 > /usr/share/nginx/site1/index.html && \
    echo Site2 > /usr/share/nginx/site2/index.html
```

You can build, run and test it like this

```
docker build -t test .
docker run -d --rm -p 8080:80 -p 8100:100 test
curl localhost:8080
curl localhost:8100
```

The 2 curl commands then return 'Site1' and 'Site2'

If you don't want to expose the ports, you can just leave out the mapping of the ports on the `docker run` command. Nginx will still listen on the ports in the container (80 and 100).

Comment: Ah I see! So, what I was trying to couldn't be accomplished with Docker environment variables or expose.